# Error: sink() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘parent’

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create an aggregated sink at organization level in GCP using python, Not sure what’s wrong, getting an error sink() got an unexpected keyword ‘parent’

I am passing parent = organizations/orgid

Below is the code

```
import requests
import json
import re
import sys
import subprocess
import os
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.cloud import logging
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from datetime import date, timedelta
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("")
filterstring = "protoPayload.methodName=google.cloud.orgpolicy.v2.OrgPolicy.CreatePolicy OR protoPayload.methodName=google.cloud.orgpolicy.v2.OrgPolicy.UpdatePolicy OR protoPayload.methodName=google.cloud.orgpolicy.v2.OrgPolicy.DeletePolicy"
orgid = ""
logging_client = logging.Client()
projectid = ""
publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

def create_topic(projectid, topicid):
    try:
        topicpath = publisher.topic_path(projectid, topicid)
        topic = publisher.create_topic(request={"name": topicpath})
        print(f"Created topic: {topic.name}")
    except Exception as e:
        pass

def create_sink(sink_name, topicid, filter_, orgid):
    destination = "pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/{}/topics/{}".format(projectid, topicid)
    sink = logging_client.sink(sink_name, filter_=filter_, parent="organizations/orgid", destination=destination)

    if sink.exists():
        print("Sink {} already exists.".format(sink.name))
    else:
        sink.create()
        print("Created sink {}".format(sink.name))

# def publishing_message(projectid, topicid):
#     publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
#     topic_path = publisher.topic_path(projectid, topicid)

#     for n in range(1, 10):
#         data_str = f"Message number {n}"
#         data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
#         future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
#         print(future.result())

#     print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    sink_name = "newsink"

    filter_ = filterstring
    topicid = "newtopic"
    create_topic(projectid, topicid)
    create_sink(sink_name, topicid, filter_, orgid)
    sinks = list(logging_client.list_sinks())
    
    for sink in sinks:
        print(dir(sink))
```

Any idea what’s wrong in the code.. want to create a sink at org level..

Comment: See the [example](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#logging_create_sink-python) in Google's documentation. There is no `parent` parameter on `logging_client.sink`.

Comment: And in the docs: https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/client.html#google.cloud.logging_v2.client.Client.sink

Comment: Am I using the wrong client? then how can I create an aggregated sink at organization level..

Comment: It appears you want to use [`Sinks`](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/sink.html) and its `create` rather than `Client`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example:

`main.py`:

```py
from google.cloud import logging
from os import getenv

name = getenv("NAME")
bucket = getenv("BUCKET")
org = getenv("ORG")

parent = f"organizations/{org}"
destination = f"storage.googleapis.com/{bucket}"

# Uses Google Application (Default) Credentials
# Service Account "sinkator" has Org roles/logging.admin
client = logging.Client()

sink = logging.Sink(
    name,
    parent=parent,
    destination=destination,
    client=client)

sink.create()
print(f"{name} {'DOES' if sink.exists() else 'NOT'} exist")
```

Then:

```sh
gcloud logging sinks describe ${NAME} \
--organization=${ORG} \
--format="value(createTime)"
```

Yields:

```
2022-04-22T00:00:00.000000000Z
```

With:

```sh
Q="71970259"
PROJECT=$(whoami)-$(date +%y%m%d)-${Q}
BUCKET=${PROJECT}
ACCOUNT="sinkator"
NAME="Freddie"

ORG=$(gcloud organizations list \
  --format="value(name)") && echo ${ORG}

gcloud project create ${PROJECT}

EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--project=${PROJECT}

gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Add Service Account to the Organizational IAM
gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding ${ORG} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/logging.admin

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json
export ORG
export BUCKET
export NAME

python3 main.py
```

Yields:

```
Freddie DOES exist
```

Comment: Thanks. Do we need some kind of permission to create sink at org level??

Comment: Getting permission denied error, added org admin role to service account..

Comment: The role binding is in my answer. The Service Account needs an organizational binding for `roles/logging.admin`